# Parsing Make expansions with pyparsing

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing

We're working on a grammar for a reduced Make syntax, and ran into a snag with nested expansions.

Here's an example of what we want to to parse:

```
$(error Not implemented for this OS: $(filter XYZ_OS_%, $(.VARIABLES)))
```

This is a variant on the nested expression problem that many people seem to struggle with. It's slightly more difficult because the nested expressions can contain free-form strings, including parentheses and dollars:

```
$(error Something went wrong (you owe me $$$$$$.))
```

(`$` chars are escaped with repetition here.)

I have a preliminary grammar for this, but I can't think of a way to define the `text` rule.

```
name = Word(alphanums + '_')
text = CharsNotIn('$)')  # This does not work generally.

expansion = Suppress('$(') + name + Suppress(')')

sub_expression = Forward()
expression = ZeroOrMore(sub_expression)

error = Suppress('$(error ') + expression + Suppress(')')
info = Suppress('$(info ') + expression + Suppress(')')
pattern = Word(alphanums + '._%')
filter = Suppress('$(filter ') + pattern + Suppress(',') + expression + Suppress(')')

sub_expression << (text | error | filter | info | expansion)

# This accepts all kinds of invalid Make syntax,
# but is useful for testing line-by-line.
test_grammar = OneOrMore(text | expansion | error | filter | info)
```

This captures the naive cases, but fails on parentheses and dollars that don't belong to expansions.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd think that you ought to handle `error`, `filter`, etc just like the general variable expansions.

Comment: @Antti, thanks, I think we just arrived at the same conclusion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help in separating text content from expansion.

Comment: That is why it is a comment... you should just find out how Make parses the expansions first, and then duplicate it, easiest that way.

Comment: Make does not appear to use a formal parser, all phases (parsing, variable expansion, macro expansion, etc.) are subtly intertwined. I would prefer not to replicate that complexity.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out!

We realized that Make allows parentheses inside `$(error)` and friends, but only if they're balanced. It has to be this way, otherwise it wouldn't know what to do with dangling expressions like:

```
$(error This(thing(is)crazy)
```

So we were missing a vital part of the grammar: the rule that matches parenthesized text inside otherwise opaque text.

Then we finally found [`SkipTo`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.SkipTo-class.html), which was the kind of thing we were originally looking for. It consumes all text until the rule passed to it is matched, which lets us do (reduced):

```
name = Word(alphanums + '_')
expansion = Suppress('$(') + name + Suppress(')')

end_of_text = Literal('$(') | Literal('(') | Literal(')')
text = NotAny(end_of_text) + SkipTo(end_of_text).leaveWhitespace()
parenthesized_text = Combine(Literal('(') + SkipTo(')').leaveWhitespace() + Literal(')'))

sub_expression = Forward()
expression = ZeroOrMore(sub_expression | parenthesized_text | text)

error = Suppress('$(error ') + expression + Suppress(')')

sub_expression << (error | expansion)

grammar = OneOrMore(error)
```

We saw that when we're inside an expression, text comes in chunks interleaved with parenthesized text and expansions. To recognize the text we look out for `$(`, which starts an expansion, `(`, which starts parenthesized text and `)`, which ends the whole thing.

Essentially, `error` matches `$(error` followed by a sequence of expressions and neatly returns them as tree. E.g.

```
$(error Something went wrong (you owe me.) Status: $(status))
```

parses into:

```
error: $(error
    text: Something went wrong
    parenthesized_text: (you owe me.)
    text: Status:
    expansion: $(status)
```

I see now that this is probably not correct, e.g. we don't recognize expansions inside parenthesized text. We'll see if we can figure it out.

The only thing I can't really explain is why `NotAny` is necessary in `text`, the parser hangs without it, so I guess it needs something to start the rule off.

Hope this helps someone else!